# Node js 5.5.0 - data even on Request Object not raised after Posting form

Tags: node.js

I am trying below code everything working fine except "data" event is not being raised and due to this i am unable to collect POSTed form data.

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");

http.createServer(function(req,res){

    if (req.method === "GET")
    {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});

        fs.createReadStream("./public/form.html","UTF-8").pipe(res);
    }

     if (req.method === "POST") 
     {

        var body = "";
        console.log("post received.");
        **req.on("data",function(){**
            var chunk="";
            console.log("chunk started");
            body +=chunk;
        });

        req.on("end", function(){
            console.log("end started");

            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});

            res.end(`<!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                <head>
                <title>Form Results</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                <h1>Your form Results:</h1>
                <p>${body}</p>
                </body>
                </html>`);
        });

    }

}).listen(3000);

console.log("FormServer is running on port 3000");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is working for me, are you sure you are sending the correct data?

Comment: Yes, its working for me also now. Not sure what was wrong with the code and i didn't changed anything and working fine. Too many hours it took and worked without even fixing it. Anyhow thanks for your answer, appreciate it.